# VB.NET Trabalhando com XML?

Tags: xml, vb.net

Estou preenchendo uma `ComboBox` a partir de um `Xml`:

```
Dim mXml As New XmlDocument
Dim Arquivo As New IO.FileInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Configuracao.xml")
mXml.Load(Arquivo.FullName)

Dim SearchMusic As New DataSet
SearchMusic.ReadXml(Arquivo.ToString)
Me.ComboBox_list.DisplayMember = "Nome"
Me.ComboBox_list.DataSource = SearchMusic.Tables(0)
SearchMusic = Nothing
```

O meu `XML` está da seguinte forma:

```
<Musicas>    
  <Musica>    
    <Nome>teste1</Nome>    
    <Path>D:\teste</Path>    
  </Musica>    
  <Musica>    
    <Nome>Teste2</Nome>  
    <Path>c:\</Path>
 </Musica>
 <Musica>    
    <Nome>Tesssste</Nome>    
    <Path>c:\Windows\</Path>    
 </Musica>    
</Musicas>
```

Preciso saber como faço para buscar o conteúdo da `tag` `Path` de acordo com o nome, exemplo:

- Escrevo `teste1` ele precisa me retornar `D:\teste`, é possível fazer isso?

Comment: Não tenho como responder agora, mas pesquise por `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

***A sua implementação inicial está redundante e falha em alguns pontos, por exemplo:***

```
Dim SearchMusic As New DataSet
SearchMusic.ReadXml(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Configuracao.xml")
Me.ComboBox_list.DisplayMember = "Nome"
Me.ComboBox_list.DataSource = SearchMusic.Tables(0)
```

já resolve aquele monte de linha desnecessária e redundante, claro estou pensando no seu código inicial que deve ser melhorado.

***A busca pode ser feita fazendo um filtro no DataTable pelo método Select:***

```
Dim SearchMusic As New DataSet
Dim Nome As String = "teste1"
Dim Result As String = ""

SearchMusic.ReadXml(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Configuracao.xml")

Dim Path = SearchMusic _
      .Tables(0) _
      .Select(String.Format("Nome = '{0}'", Nome)) _
      .FirstOrDefault()

If (Not IsNothing(Path)) Then
    Result = Path.Item("Path").ToString() // resultado esperado
End If
```

Uma outra solução pode ser feita utilizando [XDocument](http://Classe%20XDocument) do `namespace` [System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(IO.File.ReadAllText(My _
          .Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Configuracao.xml"))
If (Not IsNothing(doc)) Then
    Dim result = (From a In doc.Descendants("Musica")
     Select New With {.Nome = a.Element("Nome").Value, .Path = a.Element("Path").Value}) _
                       .ToArray()
    Dim Nome As String = "teste1"
    Dim Pesquisa = result.Where(Function(w) w.Nome = Nome).FirstOrDefault()
    If (Not IsNothing(Pesquisa)) Then
        Dim _path = Pesquisa.Path // resultado esperado
    End If
End If
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Propriedade DataView.RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [How to filter data in dataview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [XDocument](http://Classe%20XDocument)
- [Namespace System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq(v=vs.100).aspx)